# rebuilding css for specific parts and possible apply jquery if needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do some css enhancements where i need to change the the way it is being displayed, so that is on external page

this is URL:

```
<div class="group_l"><label>Area</label><br><select>
```

here is the relevant CSS for this:

```
.group_l
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

now it shows as:

```
Area
{select field}
```

and i want it to be displayed as:

```
Area: {select Field}
```

i know there is 
 tag, i think we can remove with jquery or css, whatever approach is, i wanna go with that

and apply the `:` after `Area`

There is one another thing: My select is showing of `150px;` width of all selects, how can i make it **dynamic based upon the options data** like if options data contain `1,2,3,4` . it should be of that width only

Thanks

Comment: `<br>` is a line break. This is why it shows as you mention. Is this supposed to be in your code. Also you html is not complete. Did you intend to just post the first part?

Comment: i just posted a portion of the code... yes <br> is there and i do not have  control over it as of now

Comment: How do you mean 'not have control over it'? You can't change source file?

Comment: no because it is coming from external source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [code pen](http://codepen.io/Matthewnie/pen/ZYWPgj) of what I think you are looking for.

```
.group_l {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
.group_l br {
  display: none;
}
.group_l label:after {
  content: ": ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if i have br after the label, then what will be additional code

Comment: Since you are looking to have label and the input/select display in a single line and the BR is not removable from the code we are just hiding it with display:none;

Comment: why i asked, in some cases say this: `<div class="group_l"><label>AGE</label><br><input></div>`

Comment: I have updated the codepen to try and help explain. The br is after the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/x4ycfrza/

```
var current = $(".group_l").clone();

current.find("label").text(current.find("label").text() + " : ");

current = current.html();

var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
current = current.replace(regex, "");

$(".group_l").html(current);
```